# Is there an animationDidStopSelector when performing this type of animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

I have a `UIimageView` which appears as a static image. When the image is touched it sets off an animation of 16 images in that `UIImageView`. When the animation is completed I want to set the image of the `UIImageView` to a new image. I don't know how to do this the way I currently have my code. Can anyone tell me how to go about this? I have tried using an `NSTimer` (set to the animation duration) to call another method but this doesn't really work. Here is my code. I'd appreciate any help.

```
- (void) hdFallingAnim {
    NSString *fileName; 
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
        fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FallingReg/HD_Falling_REG%d.png", i];
        [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName]];
    }
    hdFalling.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    hdFalling.animationImages = imageArray;
    hdFalling.animationDuration = 2;
    hdFalling.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    hdFalling.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:hdFalling];
    [hdFalling startAnimating];


}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a reliable way of doing that. Try this post to see how to animate images with Core Animation. Then you can use the completion delegate. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897759/animating-images-using-caanimation

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to detect this with these kinds of animations. You can poll in a background thread something like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("waste.of.resources.but.it.works", 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        while( [hdFalling isAnimating]) {
            //Waiting....
        }

        //Finished
        hdFalling.animationImages = nil;
        hdFalling.image = //Your image
    });
    dispatch_release(queue);
```